How to start cygwin with x11 support in Windows Terminal
I am using Cygwin in Windows Terminal by setting the command line option to D:\cygwin64\Cygwin.bat. It works well but now I need to have X11 support so that I can use X11 forward in ssh command.
I have no idea how to setup this. There are some similar issues but they don't provide the solution I want.

You need to start the XWin Server and then enter in the terminal:
export DISPLAY=:0.0; export GNUTERM=x11; export GNUPLOT_DRIVER_DIR=/usr/libexec/gnuplot/6.0

should then have access to x11 windows. GNUTERM and GNUPLOT_DRIVER_DIR are for gnuplot, if you need it.

It works! I don't expect it is that simple. I can just add it to .bashrc
